# Pandas derived column for number of work days between 2 dates

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, derived-column

The numpy `busdays_count` works but when I apply it to the dataframe I get errors because some of the dates are NaT (correctly).

If it was a normal array I could iterate each row, check if NaT and then apply the formulae but not sure here ...

```
data_raw['due'] = pd.to_datetime(data_raw['Due Date'], format="%Y%m%d")
data_raw['clo'] = pd.to_datetime(data_raw['Closed Date'], format="%Y%m%d")

data_raw['perf'] = data_raw.apply(lambda row: np.busday_count(row['due'].values.astype('datetime64[D]'),
                                row['clo'].values.astype('datetime64[D]')
                                if pd.isnull(row['clo'])
                                else '',
                                axis=1
                                ))
```

The error is `KeyError: 'due'`

This works below but not sure on joining:

```
p_df = data_raw[pd.notna(data_raw.clo)]
p_df['perf'] = np.busday_count(p_df['due'].values.astype('datetime64[D]'), p_df['clo'].values.astype('datetime64[D]'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around but pretty sure it is not the best way...

```
# split the dataframe
not_na = data_raw[pd.notna(data_raw.clo)]
is_na = data_raw[pd.isna(data_raw.clo)]

# do the calc without the NaNs
not_na['perf'] = 
          np.busday_count(not_na['due'].values.astype('datetime64[D]'), 
                          not_na['clo'].values.astype('datetime64[D]'))

# lastly, join the dataframes back
new_df = pd.concat([is_na, not_na], axis=0)
```